# Cookie with Max-Age = 0 and Expire = session survived after HTTP redirect?

Tags: http, web, cookies

Case:

Client makes request to server1. Server1 will set cookie `mycookie=myvalue;Max-Age=0;Expire=session`. Then server1 makes HTTP Redirect to server2. Server2 does its work and makes HTTP redirect back to server1. And this time, I see that `Cookie: mycookie=myvalue` is included. How is that possible? `Max-Age = 0` will always takes priority over `Expire = session`. HTTP redirect that was made first time still reaches browser and therefore cookie was stored on client side and due to `Max-Age = 0` should be immediately deleted.

Or I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible. The behaviour should be exactly as you expected it to be. I would propose that there could be some specific about server you use and how it handles cookies with such attributes. Which server do you use?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Well, I use just go server (like running go routine) and set cookie with net/http SetCookie method

Comment: @armaka then that makes sense. Look into [Go docs](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Cookie) for net/http carefully `// MaxAge=0 means no 'Max-Age' attribute specified`. Which then means that Expire=session will indeed be used and Max-Age not